# How to find the JAVA compilation error after committing the changes in SVN repository

Tags: java, jenkins

Sometimes someone forgets to commit their changes properly in the SVN repository. So getting java compilation error while taking new checkout from the repository or executing the script through Jenkins due to dependency missing. Is there any way to create a Jenkins job to capture the compilation errors and send it to a specified group of members?

I have created a job in Jenkins and compile the program through the windows batch command. but I am not able to send an email if the compilation errors exist.

Have to create Jenkins' job and it will be run at regular intervals to check the compilation errors. if found any error while compiling the program, mail should be sent to a specific group of members

Comment: am not using the maven.

Comment: Check out https://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/

Comment: I presume, given that you are using SVN and also not using Maven your development processes are arcane; so perhaps just get the scribe to read through the logs and inform the comitters by carrier pigeon... More seriously though, if you trigger your Jenkins job via a commit hook on the SVN repo for a **specific commit** then it is trivial to send an email on build failure to the comitter. If you, as I suspect, are doing something truly enigmatic, like polling, then things are tricker.